# If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic complex functions, is $f/g$ also holomorphic? What's the proof?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-bundles

$f$ and $g$ are both holomorphic functions on some domain $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$. Is $\frac f g$ going to be holomorphic on $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2-\{z\mid g(z)=0\}$? What's the proof?

Comment: If $g=0$, then the answer is clearly no, since $\frac fg $ is not even defined.

Comment: In the case where $g\neq  0$, what is the proof that the ratio is also holomorphic?

Comment: This is just the quotient rule. If you can derive the quotient rule you can prove $\frac{f}{g}$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
& \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)} - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} h \\[10pt]
= {} & \lim_{h\to0} \frac{ f(x+h)g(x) - f(x)g(x+h) }{h g(x+h) g(x)}\\[10pt]
= {} & \lim_{h\to0} \frac{ \Big( f(x+h)g(x) - f(x)g(x) \Big) - \Big( f(x)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)  \Big)}{hg(x)g(x+h)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \lim_{h\to0} \left( \frac 1 {g(x)g(x+h)} \left( g(x) \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h - f(x) \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)} h \right) \right) \\[15pt]
= {} & \frac{g(x)\left(\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h\right) - f(x) \left( \lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)} h \right) }{\lim_{h\to0} g(x)g(x+h)} \tag 1 \\[15pt]
= {} & \frac{g(x)f'(x) - f(x) g'(x)}{g(x)^2}
\end{align*}

In $(1)$ we used an assumption that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and a theorem that says differentiable functions are continuous.

Comment: Where do you use the fact that differentiable functions are continuous? Is it to show that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} g(x)g(x + h) \neq 0?$

Answer (score 1):

1. $g(z)\ne 0$ for $z\in \Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$.
2. Complex function is holomorphic in $\Omega$ if there exist the derivative in each point of the domain. Then in usual manner one could prove that there exist derivative $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'(z)$ for all $z\in \Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$. Actually we should to check that 
   $$
   \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'(z) = \frac{f'(z)g(z)-f(z)g'(z)}{g^2(z)}.
   $$

The proof is the same as in [real case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule#Proof) (but before they prove [product rule](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_Rule_for_Derivatives#Proof)).