# Elegant way to show $\frac{\cosh(z)}{4z^3-z}$ is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

We are calculating integrals. To use Cauchy's Theorem for punctured domains I need to show that $$f(z)=\frac{\cosh(z)}{4z^3-z}$$
is holomorphic. (The integral to be calculated is over the disk around $0$ with $r=\frac{1}{4}$)

I've tried to reshape $f$ to $f(x,iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ to use the CR-Equations. However both using polar coordinates and just straight algebra I get a huge mess, massive sums with 6+ terms.

Is there an algebraic trick or some other way to show that f is holomorphic?

Comment: Holomorphic where?

Comment: It's the quotient of two holomorphic functions, so is holomorphic except where the denominator vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is the quotient of two holomorphic functions, it is holomorphic.

Comment: So: attempt to verify the CR equations on $\cosh z$, not on that quotient.

Comment: Why? Since $\cosh$ is the sum of a power series, it is holomorphic.

Comment: The OP was trying to do his problem with the CR equations and got a mess.

Comment: I think that the natural approach is the one from my previous comment. But usinf the Cauchy-Riemann equations for checking that $\cosh$ is holomorphic is also a fine approach.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can I just use the fact that both numerator and denominator are power series to argue that the quotient must be as well? We don't have that result stated anywhere....

Comment: @RubenKruepper I would not do that. Although true, it's far from obvious.

Comment: For future readers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507298/if-f-and-g-are-holomorphic-complex-functions-is-f-g-also-holomorphic-wha has a nice proof